# Datagrid Column Collection Changed Event

Tags: wpf, datagrid, addition

I use this code to add or remove column from datagrid. each column header I have mouse enter and leave event. For new column I also would like to add the same event handler after inserting to datagrid.

```
    private void Columns_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CollectionChangeEventArgs e)
     {
        if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Add)
        {
            int columnPosition = (this.Columns.Count - 1);
            DataGridTextColumn column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Header = (e.Element as DataColumn).ColumnName;
            column.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("[{0}]", column.Header.ToString()));
            this.Columns.Insert(columnPosition, column);

            DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = DataGridHelper.GetColumnHeader(this, columnPosition);
            if (columnHeader != null)
            {
                columnHeader.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(ColumnHeader_MouseEnter);
                columnHeader.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(ColumnHeader_MouseLeave);
            }
            SetAutomappingOnOff = false;
        }
        else if (e.Action == CollectionChangeAction.Remove)
        {
            DataColumn column = e.Element as DataColumn;
            DataGridColumn toRemove = (from DataGridColumn dc in this.Columns
                                       where dc.Header != null && dc.Header.ToString() == column.ColumnName
                                       select dc).First();
            this.Columns.Remove(toRemove);
            SetAutomappingOnOff = false;
        }
    }
```

**< Edit>**

DataGridHelper

```
public static class DataGridHelper 
{ 
    public static DataGridColumnHeader GetColumnHeader(DataGrid dataGrid, int index) 
    { 
        DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>(dataGrid); 
        if (presenter != null) { 
             return (DataGridColumnHeader)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index)‌​; 
        } 
        return null; 
    }
}
```

**< /Edit>**

But columnHeader always returns null even though I can see that object is created and added to datagrid.

Pls help me.

Thanks
Dee

Comment: What is DataGridHelper and how does it get the column header?

Comment: public static class DataGridHelper
    {
        public static DataGridColumnHeader GetColumnHeader(DataGrid dataGrid, int index)
        {
            DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter>(dataGrid);

            if (presenter != null)
            {
                return (DataGridColumnHeader)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
            }

            return null;
        }}

Answer (score 0):

While the column has been added to the DataGrid, it hasn't yet been added to the VisualTree so your FindVisualChild method is returning null. I don't have a good solution for adding the click handler for the column, but you could add it to the DataGrid and check the sender to see where to apply the click handling logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest registering `CollectionChanged` event on `DataGrid`-s `Loaded` event. That way you can be sure that `DataGridColumnHeader` is added to the visual tree. It will look like this:

```
myDataGrid.Loaded += (s,e) => {
    myCollection.CollectionChanged += (se, ev) => {
        //do work here
    };
};
```